# What is a name for a (re)presentation of a group that is not a "group representation" or "group presentation"

Tags: group-theory, terminology

In group theory, "representation" and "presentation" have specific meanings. I want to express something different and must avoid using these words. I want a term that essentially means "which isomorphism you choose".

For example, suppose $G$ is a group such that:

- $G\cong$ Aut$(D_{2n})$
- $G\cong$ Hol$(C_n)$

i.e., $G$ is the automorphism group of the dihedral group of order $2n$ and $G$ is also the holomorph of the cyclic group of order $n$. Even though these (re)present $G$, they are not "(re)presentations" of $G$. These are essentially two equivalent ways of writing or referring to $G$. Are these descriptions, characterizations, names, labels, or something else? If there's not a standard term for this, what words would at least work?

Comment: Why not call them what they are?

Comment: A presentation gives a combinatorial means of working with a group, and a representation gives a linear algebraic means of working with it. By specifying it is isomorphic to a known group, you are just naming it, you are telling us what it is.

Comment: Although not very common: realization?

Comment: +1 for realization

Comment: You can call it a representative of $G$'s isomorphism class. In analogy to equivalence classes and their representatives.

Comment: @NickyHekster So I could say for example, "this group can be realized in the following ways" or "the following are realizations of this group"?

Comment: Yeah that’s the idea!